# Stop Caching Of Hotlinked Images

Tags: html, asp.net, caching

I have a website that makes forum tickers. Counters that tell people their progress towards a certain goal.

These tickers are generated by my asp.net back end and are rendered into a jpg, these are then hotlinked so i can update them periodically.

However browsers are caching my images when they are hotlinked from other websites (forum signatures mainly).

I know i can stop caching of images on my own website by adding a random query string to each image request on a page. But does anyone know of a way to disable caching of images when they are hotlinked?

Not sure if its even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same approach will work for an external/hot-linked resource. Such "cache busting" applies to all requests; because the requested resource itself is *different* (by some 'unique id' that is part of the URL) the browser cannot cache it.

Comment: Just tell the server to send out appropriate cache headers